# How to store failed login attempts in React using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

A React app is build with Sign-in with Google options using Firebase. The app needs to track the number of failed attempts to login in Redux and if user enters wrong password more than twice, show reCaptcha component.

Right now, the ReCaptcha component loads every time the page is loaded. It should load only when user enters wrong password more than 2 times.

Sign-in page :

```
render() {
  return (
     //Sign-in with Email component
     ....
     // ReCaptcha component
     ....
  );
}
```

Reducer function :

```
const initialState = {
  failedLoginAttempts: 0
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'UPDATE_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        failedLoginAttempts: //how to increment the count by 1??
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: The above reducer code works when we dispatch it when Email/Password is wrong. In case of Sign-in with Google where FirebaseUI component is used, how to dispatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> failedLoginAttempts: //how to increment the count by 1??

Just use the current value of `state.failedLoginAttempts` and add 1:

```
return {
  ...state,
  failedLoginAttempts: state.failedLoginAttempts + 1
};
```

Use `mapStateToProps` to map `failedLoginAttempts` as prop. Then use it to show the captcha.

```
mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    failedLoginAttempts: state.failedLoginAttempts,
  }
}

render () {
  if (props.failedLoginAttempts > 2) {
    // show captcha
    return <Captcha />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. How to load the ReCaptcha component only when failedLoginAttempts > 2 ?

Comment: @Sneh the update is just showing the basic logic how to show captcha when `failedLoginAttempts > 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do by increment count from previous one :

```
const initialState = {
  failedLoginAttempts: 0
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'UPDATE_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        failedLoginAttempts: state.failedLoginAttempts+1 //Update attempt from last one
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached the Action.js file, but in my opinion, the best way to listen to failed anything in Redux is { catch } the action -

---

```
export const Login = user => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN',
            payload: user 
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_ERR',
            err
          });
      }
  };
};
```

---

and then in the reducer

---

```
const initialState = {
   attempts: 0 //in case that you want to increase the failed attempts only on second hit
   failedLoginAttempts: 0
  };

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
   switch (type) {
     case 'LOGIN':
        return {
         ...state,
          //do something with the succseful user
       };
    case 'LOGIN_ERR':
       if (state.attempts === 1) {
       return {
        ...state,
        failedLoginAttempts: state.failedLoginAttempts + 1
        attempts: 0
       }
      } else { return { ...state, attempts: 1 } }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

---